# spark session build taking long time

Tags: python, apache-spark

I am new to Spark and Hadoop. I have installed both within docker container.

In `spark-submit` we are calling the python script

we are trying to execute below in `spark-submit`

```
 spark = (
        pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder
        .appName('AppName ')
        .config('spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled', 'true')
        .config('spark.sql.shuffle.partitions', 2000)
        .config('spark.debug.maxToStringFields', 1000)
        .getOrCreate())
```

it is not showing any errors but getting stuck

Comment: try to use .master('local') below appname

Comment: Hi @AleGallagher Yes i am able to solve it

Comment: adding .master("local") to above commands worked